# What does 'pay' mean in this phrase, "to pay a female to make similar decisions based on the quality of her mate"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does 'pay' mean in below context?
"The female deer were choosing their offspring's sex based on their own condition. But it can also pay a female to make similar decisions based on the quality of her mate."

Comment: Think of it as "paying" money metaphorically.

Answer (score 1):

to bring about a good result or benefit; to benefit

See Definition 3 in [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pay)

> **to give or afford (a person) a profit or benefit**
>
> *it pays one to be honest*

Note that the "person" in the article is a deer.

Note this same meaning of pay is found earlier in the article in:

> Fisher argued that the sex ratio ought to be self-correcting. If there are more males than females in a population, on average each male will get less than one mate. That means it would **pay** parents to produce female offspring, as that would give them a better chance of having grandchildren and thus preserving their genes.

Comment: Also "pay for" can be used.